# set two radio buttons in one row then next two radio is on second row and so on

Tags: android, android-layout, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, radio-group

i want to set 2 two radiobuttons one row , then next 2 radiobuttons on second row dynamically(Programmatically) I am new to android any body have idea or sample code of it. What i have do is:

```
RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup01);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
    rdbtn.setId(i);
    rdbtn.setText("test");

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    ll.addView(rdbtn);
    radiogroup.addView(rdbtn);
    ll.addView(radiogroup);
    //i%2 == 0
}
```

Comment: try to use tablelayout table and tablerow

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

**Activity code**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for(int row=0; row < 5; row++) 
         {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
                rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
                rdbtn.setText("test " + rdbtn.getId());
                ll.addView(rdbtn);
            }
            ((ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(ll);
         }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output on screen**:

[image]
Hope this is what you were looking for. Cheers!

Comment: We can replace LinearLayout with RadioGroup in case you specifically need to use RadioGroup. I have updated my answer. It still gives the same output.

Comment: Any Solution for At A Time only one  radio remains selected